# An infinite series involving enumeration of rationals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ (r_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Consider the map $$ f(x) := \sum_{k \text{ such that } r_k < x} \frac{1}{2^k} $$ with $f(0) = 0$.

Does this function jump at every rational in $(0,1]$ independently of the choice of enumeration of the rationals?

I suspect it does, however I think there is a counter example: if one chooses an enumeration that starts $(1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \dots)$, then for $x \in (1/2, 1]$ we have already summed over the first 'infinitely many' values of $k$ and as such will be arbitrarily close to $1$. Hence we cannot jump by any $\varepsilon >0$ as we are already less than $\varepsilon$ away from $1$. So for this enumeration there are no jumps after $x = 1/2$. Is this reasoning correct?

---

EDIT: as is pointed out in the comments, the key error is that the suggested enumeration fails.

Comment: The flaw in the argument is that summing infinitely many terms in the sequence $\{\frac1{2^k}\}$ isn't the same as summing all of the terms in the sequence $\{\frac1{2^k}\}$.

Comment: Your enumeration does not seem to enumerate ***all*** rationals in [0,1] - I mean, if it continues like it started.

Comment: I don't understand your pattern $\{1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ...\}$.  If it is just $1/n$ then you will never list all of the rationals in $(0,1)$. $$\{1/n\}_{n=2}^{\infty} \subsetneq \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$$

Comment: @IvanNeretin is it not possible to have an enumeration of the rationals that starts by enumerating all rationals of the form $1/k$? This is something I know nothing of and can't seem to find formal definitions of, but intuitively it seems reasonable to me that we can _start_ by enumerating those?

Comment: No, it is not possible. By the time you are done with all $1\over k$ and move on to, say, $2\over3$, you'll have run out of integers to enumerate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are closer than any $\epsilon$ to $1,$ that means that we have enumerated **all** the rationals. Which means that the interval $[x, 1]$ has **NO** rationals in it. Do you think that is plausible?

Comment: I think my issue is with the definition of an enumeration. Could you clarify why it is not possible to have enumerated infinitely many rationals before we reach the end of the interval?

Comment: @MaxMackie it is possible to enumerate infinitely many, just not *all*.

Comment: And the reason for that is exactly the argument I give in the answer.